# Numerical integration converging too slowly. how to over come this

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I have a function U1 which contains a linear combination of trigonometric function, I wanted to Numerically integrate this function U1. Since each trigonometric functions associated with some unknown coefficients. I use coefficient rules to separate the unknown coefficients and associated functions. I later used Nintegrate to carry out numerical integration. But I am getting warnings," Numerical integration converging too slowly, suspect singularity" (`NIntegrate::slwcon`, `NIntegrate::ncvb`).
how to overcome this?

```
L2 = 1;
fixedfree = Table[Sin[(2*i - 1)/(2*L2)*\[Pi]*x2], {i, 1, 3}];
fixedfixed = Table[Sin[(i*\[Pi]*x2)/L2], {i, 1, 3}];
barmodes = Flatten[{fixedfree, fixedfixed}];

U1 = Expand[
   Total[Table[b[i]*barmodes[[i]], {i, 1, Length[barmodes]}]]];
U1x = Expand[D[U1, {x2, 1}]];
in3 = Expand[(U1x)^2];
in4 = Expand[(U1)^2];
var2 = Table[b[i], {i, 1, Length[barmodes]}]

rules3 = CoefficientRules[in3, var2];
rules3[[All, 2]] = NIntegrate[rules3[[All, 2]], {x2, 0, L2}];
v2 = 0.5*a2*Y2*(FromCoefficientRules[rules3, var2])

rules4 = CoefficientRules[in4, var2];
rules4[[All, 2]] = NIntegrate[rules4[[All, 2]], {x2, 0, L2}];
t2 = 0.5*r*a2*q^2*(FromCoefficientRules[rules4, var2])
```

Comment: Using `Integrate` instead of `NIntegrate` instantly finds all your integrals exactly and with zero error or warning messages

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that some of the integrals vanish (also suggested in the `NIntegrate::slwcon` warning), which makes it impossible to achieve an error goal determined exclusively by relative precision.  This is what happens by default, because the setting for `AccuracyGoal` is `Infinity`.  Use a finite `AccuracyGoal` that is appropriate for the magnitude of the integrand and the working precision.  For machine precision and the integrands in `rules4`, which have maxima on the order of `10^0 == 1`, use `$MachinePrecision` or `16`.

```
NIntegrate[rules4[[All, 2]], {x2, 0, L2}, AccuracyGoal -> $MachinePrecision]
(*
{0.5, 0., -5.55112*10^-17, 0.848826, -0.339531, 0.21827, 0.5, 
 5.55112*10^-17, 0.509296, 0.727565, -0.282942, 0.5, -0.121261, 
 0.565884, 0.694494, 0.5, -9.10214*10^-18, 6.7447*10^-17, 0.5, 
 2.22967*10^-16, 0.5}
*)
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error, I just copy the same thing what you have mentioned in your answer. still getting the same error

Comment: Well, choose an `AccuracyGoal` that is "appropriate for the magnitude of the integrand and the working precision" -- how large are the maxima of the integrands in `rule3`?

Comment: @acoustics  You might find it easier, too, if you split your code up, so that the troublesome lines of code are isolated.  (It would also help you improve your question, by writing a *minimal working example," omitting the annoying things that have nothing to do with the problem, like the plots.)

Comment: @acoustics Did you figure out how to adjust the `AccuracyGoal` for the integral of `rules3`?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the error messages in a slightly modified way of your approach(Thanks to the hint of Michael E2):

First find the different functions

```
fkt = Cases[U1, _ Sin[s_] -> Sin[s] , Infinity](* time dependent*)
```

Second get the coefficients(symboliq or numeric)

```
coef = Map[Coefficient[U1, #] &, fkt]
(*{b[1], b[4], b[2], b[5], b[3], b[6]} *)
U1 == coef.fkt
(*True*)
```

Integration

```
Integrate[U1, {x2, 0, L2}] // AbsoluteTiming 
(*time 0.11*)
coef.NIntegrate[fkt, {x2, 0, L2},AccuracyGoal -> 10] // AbsoluteTiming
(*time=0.05*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can change functions with zero means on others, having non-zero means by adding a constant, e.g. and

```
rules4[[All, 2]] = NIntegrate[rules4[[All, 2]] + 1, {x2, 0, L2}] - NIntegrate[1, {x2, 0, L2}]
```